# git: track more than one remote branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

In our git repository we have several branches, most of which are not used daily and contain gigabytes of information.

As such, I usually work tracking the remote branch I am using:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://sever/repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/devel:refs/remotes/origin/devel
```

How can I add an extra branch to be fetched from remote?

Comment: Do you simply want to add another branch to be treated like `devel`, that is you want a local branch called `foo` that fetches from `origin/foo`?

Comment: `git branch new_branch` `git push origin new_branch` But when you clone the repo you clone all of them ;) with the gigabyte of informations.

Answer (score 1):

The [Refspec page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) does mention:

> You can also specify multiple refspecs for fetching in your configuration file.
>   If you want to always fetch the `master` and `experiment` branches, add two lines:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/experiment:refs/remotes/origin/experiment
```

That would allow you to fetch only those two branches from your big remote repo.